# Running a file present on host using docker without copying it

Tags: docker

I have built and test a docker image`customop:latest`. No there are certain files on my host system that I want to run using this docker image. So, for example, I have this file `sample.py` in my pwd and I want to run it using docker **but without copying it on docker**.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Use a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path ...`

Comment: Why does it need to run in Docker, instead of, say, a [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments)?

Comment: Thanks @leopal. Mounting is the right option

Comment: @DavidMaze because I need to use docker only